# prototype_helpers in rails 3 with jquery - should i still use the jrails plugin? or is there a different way now?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jrails

I'm just getting to grips with rails 3.  My latest speedbump is to do with the prototype helpers i use in js.rjs files.  In some of my rails 2 apps, i ditched prototype in favour of jquery, and that's what i've done here.  To get the helpers, eg `page.replace` & `page.replace_html` back, i then used the jrails plugin which replicated the functionality but using jquery instead of prototype (or at least that was my understanding of it).

I'm using jquery instead of prototype in my toy rails 3 app and have hit the same problem: the page.replace helper doesn't work:

I have this code in `update.js.rjs`:

```
page.alert "posted"
page.replace "tweets", :partial => "twitter/tweets"
```

which causes this error from line 2 (the alert runs fine):

`RJS error:  TypeError: Element.replace is not a function`

Do i just need to install the jrails plugin again?  Or is there a different solution these days?

grateful for any thoughts - max

EDIT - i get the same problem when i move the code from a js.rjs file into my controller, like so:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js do 
    render :update do |page|
      page.alert "posted"
      page.replace "tweets", :partial => "twitter/tweets"
    end  
  end
end
```

EDIT - in the end, for lack of anything else, i just installed the jrails gem and it seems fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the [jquery-rails](https://github.com/indirect/jquery-rails) gem. This will replace prototype helpers with jquery helpers by providing a rails.js file. Add

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

to your gemfile,

```
bundle install
rails g jquery:install
```

to install the gem and generate the correct files.

Comment: i have this gem already (0.2.7) and it's listed in my Gemfile.  I added details of the error to my OP in case that helps.

Comment: @Max Williams I just updated my answer. Have you run the two commands listed?

Comment: yes i've done those as well.  I ran the second one again just in case and it reported that the existing files were identical (so didn't replace them).

Comment: btw i solved this by just installing (and calling in Gemfile) the jrails gem.

Comment: Thanks. That will help me in the future.